# prefetch instruction in JVM/JAVA

Tags: java, jvm, jit

Is there any software prefetching instructions in Java language or JVM, like [__builtin_prefetch](http://scripts.mit.edu/~birge/blog/accelerating-code-using-gccs-prefetch-extension/) which is available in GCC

Comment: What are you needing that for? Btw, this seems to be related and might provide an answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056407/java-and-cache-memory-prefetching-and-alignment

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One interesting thing is that Hotspot JVM actually **does support** prefetch!
It treats `Unsafe.prefetchRead()` and `Unsafe.prefetchWrite()` methods as intrinsics and compiles them into corresponding CPU instructions.

Unfortunately, `sun.misc.Unsafe` does not declare such methods. But, if you add the following methods to Unsafe.java, recompile it and replace Unsafe.class inside rt.jar (or just add `-Xbootclasspath/p` JVM argument) you would be able to use prefetch intrinsics in your application.

```
public native void prefetchRead(Object o, long offset);
public native void prefetchWrite(Object o, long offset);
public static native void prefetchReadStatic(Object o, long offset);
public static native void prefetchWriteStatic(Object o, long offset);
```

I doubt this could help much in real applications, but if you'd like to play with it, I can provide more details.
Here is a compiled patch to JDK 8 that enables prefetch methods: [download](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7LUxTf0AV-faDBWRzE3UzVFa2M)

Usage example:

```
long[] array = new long[100*1024*1024];
// ...
sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchReadStatic(array, 50*1024*1024);
```

**UPDATE**

`Unsafe.prefetch*` intrinsics are completely [removed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068977) in JDK 9:

> Note read/write prefetch support was implemented as an experiment to
>   see if JDK library code could use it for performance advantages.
>   However, the results of the experiment did not indicate this was
>   worthwhile. As a consequence there are no corresponding prefetch
>   native method declarations in sun.misc.Unsafe.

Comment: Good. 1) According to http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=27010.0 , they are present in hotspot intrinsic. So there is no need to recompile anything. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, Hotspot JVM already knows about the intrinsics, but they should be declared in the class library. So you'll need to either patch `rt.jar` (replace Unsafe.class) or prepend the [modified Unsafe.class](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7LUxTf0AV-faDBWRzE3UzVFa2M) to boot classpath using `-Xbootclasspath/p` flag.

Comment: Can you comment on `-XX:AllocatePrefetchLines` JVM option? Does it enable prefetch?

Comment: @neverov All `AllocatePrefetch*` options are related to emitting `prefetch` instructions right after object allocation in Java Heap. This is controlled by `-XX:AllocatePrefetchStyle` option which is ON by  default. `AllocatePrefetchLines` and `AllocateInstancePrefetchLines` control how far (in number of cache lines) to prefetch after the address of allocated object, for an array or an object respectively.